# mod_geoip + Apache 2.2 in fcgid mode

Tags: php, apache, geoip

Is there a way to get mod_geoip working when Apache 2.2 is running in fcgid mode?

I just installed it but get the following php error when I try a test:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_note() in /var/www/abc.com/geoip/index.php on line 4

Comment: Can you post your vhost configuration?

Comment: I found a way around it, when mod_geoip is installed it enables some new server variables that can be accessed directly.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around it, when mod_geoip is installed it enables some new server variables that can be accessed directly in PHP or .htaccess